# Compile time check if sizeof...(args) matches result from constexpr function

Tags: c++, c++14, constexpr, sfinae

I have constexpr function which counts number of placeholders https://godbolt.org/g/JcxSiu,

e.g: "`Hello %1`" returns `1`, and "`Hello %1, time is %2`" returns `2`.

Then I would like to make a function which does not compile if number of arguments does not equal to number of placeholders.

```
template <typename... Args>
 inline std::string make(const char* text, Args&&... args) {
   constexpr static unsigned count = sizeof...(args);

   // TODO how to compile time check if count == count_placeholders(text)    
  // constexpr static auto np = count_placeholders(text);

  //static_assert(count == np;, "Wrong number of arguments in make");

  return std::to_string(count);
};
```

so that 
`make("Hello %1", "World");` compiles and

`make("Hello %1 %2", "World");` or `make("Hello %1", "World", "John");` does not.

I think it can be done, I just don`t know how. Maybe with some template magick :)

**EDIT**

I almost get what I want. https://godbolt.org/g/Y3q2f8

Now aborts in debug mode. It is possible to make compile time error?

Comment: This is **not an answer** as it uses gnu extension buf if it does not bother you you can make use of [string literal template](https://wandbox.org/permlink/bSLW5DNEX4gNuDyw). This will work on gcc and clang but probably not on any other compiler...

Comment: This is probably not an acceptable answer either, but here is a solution that uses a macro from Boost.Metaparse. [Example](https://godbolt.org/g/tZYzyH).

Answer (score 2):

My first idea was to enable/disable `make()` using SFINAE; something like

```
template <typename... Args>
auto make(const char* text, Args&&... args)
   -> std::enable_if_t<sizeof...(args) == count_placeholders(text),
                       std::string>
 {
    // ... 
 }
```

Unfortunately this didn't compile because `text` can't be used in a `constexpr`.

But, if you accept that `text` is a template argument (so known at compile time), you can do something as

```
template <char const * const text, typename ... Args>
auto makeS (Args && ... args)
   -> std::enable_if_t<sizeof...(args) == count_plc(text), std::string>
 { return std::to_string(sizeof...(args)); }
```

The following is a full working example

```
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

constexpr std::size_t count_plc (char const * s,
                                 std::size_t index = 0U,
                                 std::size_t count = 0U)
 {
   if ( s[index] == '\0' )
      return count;
   else if (    (s[index] == '%')  && (s[index+1U] != '\0')
             && (s[index+1U] > '0') && (s[index+1U] <= '9') )
      return count_plc(s, index + 1U, count+1U);
   else
      return count_plc(s, index + 1U, count); 
 }

template <char const * const text, typename ... Args>
auto makeS (Args && ... args)
   -> std::enable_if_t<sizeof...(args) == count_plc(text), std::string>
 { return std::to_string(sizeof...(args)); }

constexpr char const h1[] { "Hello %1" };
constexpr char const h2[] { "Hello %1 %2" };

int main ()
 {
   makeS<h1>("World"); // compile
   //makeS<h2>("World"); // compilation error
   //makeS<h1>("World", "John"); // compilation error
 }
```

Comment: Indeed: arguments of constexpr functions can not be used as constexpr values. Two other possibilities (if you do not want to restrict yourself to a `const char*` as the non-type template parameter: (1) [`make<count_placeholders(text)>(text, "Hello", "World");`](https://godbolt.org/g/QfjRgf) or (2) (C++17?) [`make([=] { return text; }, "Hello", "World");`](https://godbolt.org/g/DHWbpM).